# How to use FileDateTime Function in MS Report Builder(SSRS)

Tags: vba, reporting-services, reference

I want to get file's lastmodified date via filepath in MS Report Builder. I am trying to use FileDateTime or GetFileInfo function (visual basic)

Firstly I add Microsoft.VisualBasic reference in report builder. Then I add the code as below.

But when I run report, the result of Code.ModifiedDate("") result is *#Error*.
I think the problem is in my reference but I didn't solve.

```
Public Function ModifiedDate(ByVal s As String) As String

Dim result As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileDateTime("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\name.jpg").ToShortDateString

   return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is vba, you have to assign the return value to the function name, like:

```
ModifiedDate = result
```

No `return` statement needed.

Comment: It doesnt matter I think. My problem is about Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileDateTime function. Function doesnt work and throw #Error in report. I think possible reason is 

- I could not add the relevant reference to the function properly
or
- Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileDateTime can't be used in SSRS. 

But I don't know which one is the reason.

Comment: `return result` will still never work, unless your function is calles "result" (in VBA)